# Visual Studio 2013 SSDT - Support for SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I have a question for someone out there who has Visual Studio 2013 - SSDT installed... I know that we cannot deploy SSIS packages to a SQL Server version less than 2014, what about SSRS reports? Everyone on my team except the database guys have been using VS2013 for some time now. I want to upgrade too!!! If I convinced the business to upgrade the SSIS servers to 2014, we would still need to support SSRS reports in 2008R2 (because of SharePoint 2010). Arggg... Leave it to Microsoft to leave the database developers behind (again). A new version of Visual Studio is out for preview and I don't want to be two versions behind.

Can someone please check to see if you can deploy an SSRS report to a 2008 R2 server using Visual Studio 2013? I know it's a long shot. Otherwise, I'll have to go through the massive 2013 install just to have my dreams crushed when it doesn't work out..

Thanks All!

Comment: Can you not check with a mmber of your team? You say they have already upgraded.

Comment: I don't know about VS 2013, but I use VS 2012 for my SSRS reports with our SQL Server 2008 R2 and have no issues.

Comment: Thanks April, that's what we're doing too... DB101 - No, because only the database people have SSDT/SSDT - BI installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSDT-BI 2014 for VS 2013 can support SSRS 2008 R2. It just can't support SSIS 2008R2. Please see the blog below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/03/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx